# How to plot single pixel values from 3d NumPy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a stack of 7 images of `288 x 288` pixels that I have converted to a 3d NumPy array

```
newarray.shape = (288, 288, 7)
```

I want to plot a particular pixel value from each of the 7 images and plot it as a graph with y axis showing pixel values and x axis showing the image number.

Answer (score 2):

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# NumPy array storing images
images = np.random.randint(0, 255, (288, 288, 7), np.uint8)

# Get pixel values across all images of pixel of interest
x, y = (8, 3)
pixels = images[y, x, :]

# Plot
plt.plot(np.arange(images.shape[2]), pixels)
plt.ylim(0, 255)
plt.title('Pixel values for x=' + str(x) + ', y=' + str(y))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Hope that helps!

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:    Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:      3.8.1
Matplotlib:  3.2.0rc3
NumPy:       1.18.1
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Uncannily similar to what I had, even down to the code comments 

Comment: @MarkSetchell _Great minds think alike_ - literally. ;-)

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you @HansHirse and Mark Setchell. Great minds indeed.